# How to delete a variable in a Scientific.IO.NetCDF.NetCDFFile?

Tags: python, netcdf

Is it possible to delete a variable from a `Scientific.IO.NetCDF.NetCDFFile`? If a file is opened like so:

```
nc = Scientific.IO.NetCDF.NetCDFFile("File.nc", "a")
```

neither a

```
del nc.variables["var"]
```

nor a

```
nc.variables["var"] = None
```

will delete the variable `var`.
Thx in advance for any insight.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The simple answer is that you can not delete a variable. This is a "feature" of the NetCDF C-API and is not a shortcoming of Scientific.IO.NetCDF or any of the other python netcdf modules.

From the official [NetCDF user guide:](http://www.unidata.ucar.edu/software/netcdf/docs/netcdf.html)
Attributes are more dynamic than variables or dimensions; they can be deleted and have their type, length, and values changed after they are created, whereas the netCDF interface provides no way to delete a variable or to change its type or shape.

The problem can be solved indirectly, by copying everything except the offending variable to a new NetCDF file.