# How to copy variables from one netCDF4 file to another?

Tags: python, netcdf4

I'm trying to duplicate a netCDF4 file with only a subset of the original variables. After creating a new variable using the netCDF4-python library, how do I set it to be equal to a variable in a different file?

Comment: Can you post the code you've tried so far?

Comment: See this answer, which gives an example. https://stackoverflow.com/a/48769042/1211981