# ValueError could not broadcast where mask from shape (1) into shape ()

Tags: python, python-2.7, netcdf, netcdf4, masked-array

There are a lot of questions related to `ValueError`s where input arrays of different shape cannot be broadcast here at SO. But there are none are related to masks:

```
ValueError could not broadcast where mask from shape (1) into shape ()
```

What I'm doing is the following:

- go through all variables in (the root group of) a NetCDF 4 file
- copy their content from one NetCDF file into another, newly created one

The reason why is irrelevant for this question, but may be found in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15141563/7431523).

Minimal code:

```py
with netCDF4.Dataset(inputFile) as src, \
            netCDF4.Dataset(outputFile, "w") as dst:
    
    # copy global attributes all at once via dictionary
    dst.setncatts(ingroup.__dict__)

    for variable in src.variables.values():
        # create dimensions first
        for dimName in variable.dimensions:
            dst.createDimension(
                        dimName,
                        (len(dimension)
                            if not dimension.isunlimited() else None))

        # now create variable
        newVar = outgroup.createVariable(
                variable.name,
                variable.datatype,
                variable.dimensions)

        # copy variable attributes all at once via dictionary
        newVar.setncatts(variable.__dict__)

        # copy content
        newVar[:] = variable[:]
```

This works on newer Pythons (tested with >= 3.6) for all variables, but does not with **Python 2.7**<sup>†</sup> for scalar NetCDF variables that are not filled. Within the debugger, right when this exception is raised, the variable of interest looks like (in *both* Python 2.7 and 3.6):

```py
>>> variable.shape
()
>>> type(variable[:])
<class 'numpy.ma.core.MaskedConstant'>
>>> variable[:].mask
array(True, dtype=bool)
>>> variable[:]
masked
>>> print(variable[:])
--
```

So this only happens on *empty* scalar NetCDF variables. Assigning a masked constant to another masked constant on the other hand works. It's just that masked constant inside the `netCDF4._netCDF4.Variable` .Why? And how to fix?

edit: failure occurs with numpy 1.7.1 and netcdf4 1.2.7. <- this turned out to be the source of the issue, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62579370/7431523).

---

`variable` is of type [`netCDF4._netCDF4.Variable`](https://unidata.github.io/netcdf4-python/netCDF4/index.html#netCDF4.Variable), and
`print(dir(variable))` shows `['__array__', '__class__', '__delattr__', '__delitem__', '__doc__', '__format__', '__getattr__', '__getattribute__', '__getitem__', '__hash__', '__init__', '__len__', '__new__', '__orthogonal_indexing__', '__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__', '__repr__', '__setattr__', '__setitem__', '__sizeof__', '__str__', '__subclasshook__', '__unicode__', '_assign_vlen', '_cmptype', '_enumtype', '_get', '_getdims', '_getname', '_grp', '_grpid', '_has_lsd', '_iscompound', '_isenum', '_isprimitive', '_isvlen', '_name', '_nunlimdim', '_put', '_toma', '_varid', '_vltype', 'assignValue', 'chunking', 'datatype', 'delncattr', 'dimensions', 'dtype', 'endian', 'filters', 'getValue', 'get_var_chunk_cache', 'getncattr', 'group', u'long_name', 'mask', 'name', 'ncattrs', 'ndim', 'renameAttribute', 'scale', 'set_auto_mask', 'set_auto_maskandscale', 'set_auto_scale', 'set_var_chunk_cache', 'setncattr', 'setncattr_string', 'setncatts', 'shape', 'size']`

---

<sub><sup>†</sup> Yes I know Python 2 is EOL. But it is needed for [insert reason from legacy dev environment].</sub>

Comment: What does `print(dir(variable))` show?

Comment: output too long for comment, will update question..

Comment: What does `print(variable[:])` show both in Py3.6 and Py2.7?

Answer (score 2):

If the documentation is referring to your same version, when the `shape` is an empty tuple, you could be using either [`netCDF4.Variable.getValue()`](https://unidata.github.io/netcdf4-python/netCDF4/index.html#netCDF4.Variable.getValue) / [`netCDF4.Variable.assignValue()`](https://unidata.github.io/netcdf4-python/netCDF4/index.html#netCDF4.Variable.assignValue) combination, e.g.:

```
if variable.shape:
    newVar[:] = variable[:]
else:
    newVar.assignValue(variable.getValue())
```

or `newVar[...] = variable[...]`, e.g.:

```
slicing = slice(None) if variable.shape else Ellipsis
newVar[slicing] = variable[slicing]
```

Comment: unfortunately, `getValue()` raises an `IndexError: to retrieve values from a non-scalar variable, use slicing.` At the same time, your slicing proposition raises the same ValueError, just like using [:] does. still, your comment and your answer pointed me in the right direction: testing for the variable shape! therefor, upvote.

`newVar[:] = variable[:] if variable.shape else numpy.array([])` is the solution (maintains Python 3 compatibility as well)

Comment: should I post an answer myself with the solution?

Comment: I think this is because you tried to use `getValue()` on a non-scalar variable, otherwise I see no reason why the above code should not be working, but your code seems to be losing the value of `variable` if it is a scalar.

Comment: @hintze if you think that is going to help future readers, I do not see why not.

Comment: You are right, I did not take care enough. Now testing for the shape (`newVar[:] = variable[:] if variable.shape else newVar.assignValue(variable.getValue())`) raises again the original `ValueError` at the very same variable. Strange.

Comment: @hintze This is because you are doing it incorrectly. It should be: `if variable.shape: newVar[:] = variable[:] else: newVar.assignValue(variable.getValue())` (must be in multiple lines). See edits.

Comment: I'm sorry, I tried both. Both fail with the same result (most probably in different ways). The conditional expression was a mistake on my side. Actually, I'm now wondering why the conditional expression is even syntactically allowed, `assignValue` seems to return something.

Comment: @hintze Every function returns something in Python, if nothing is set explicitly, it sets `None`.

Answer (score 1):

As surfaced through [@norok2](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5218354/norok2)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62576877/7431523), neither using `getValue()` nor slicing with Ellipsis on scalar variables works in this case. Both raises (unexpectedly) the same `ValueError` on scalar NetCDF variables with Python 2.7. Nevertheless, based on the answer, the following is derived, which fixes the problem by not setting the newly created scalar NetCDF variable.

```py
if isinstance(variable[:], numpy.ma.core.MaskedConstant):
    if variable[:].mask[()]:
        continue
newVar[:] = variable[:]
```

The result is correct, since the original `variable` is not copied to `newVar` only if it is a) scalar and b) masked (unset). Not copying means that `newVar` remains unset. Which is the same as if it would have been copied.

---

This issue appears to be version specific. With numpy 1.10.0 up until numpy 1.12.1, the raised exception changes to

```
IndexError: too many indices for array
```

Since numpy 1.13.0, this is working perfectly.

This [GitHub issue](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/6723) seems to be linked.