# copying a list in chunks of roughly equal size

Tags: python, list, copy

i need to copy a set of variables in python. what i do now is:

```
for var in variables:
  newvar[:] = var[:]
```

which works in my local machine since i have 16 gigs of ram at my dispose. Problem is on the development machine i'm supposed to use, there's only 1 gig of ram available, which cause Memory error. To fix this i thought to divide the lists i'm copying in chunks, However the variables involved could have an arbitrary level of nesting such as:

```
var1[100]
var2[50,100]
var3[20,30,50]
```

is there any library or process to copy the variables in chunks so that the chunks' size doesn't exceed the amount of the free ram available ?

Comment: Can you clarify why you need to copy into memory? Usually, using iterators/streaming will allow you to process data without copying it upfront.

Comment: i need to  delete some variables from a netcdf file, which isn't possible by itself, so i'm creating a copy of the file discarding the variables i don't need, for reference: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6816613/how-to-delete-a-variable-in-a-scientific-io-netcdf-netcdffile